# Cordova - Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using phonegap for my mobile project. My question is why I got this error when I try to search phonegap plugin using cordova CLI? I run this command in terminal to search phonegap plugin

```
cordova plugin search bar code
```

Full error message

```
Last login: Wed Jan 22 15:04:09 on ttys000
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:~ mohammadnurdin$ cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:native mohammadnurdin$ cordova plugin search bar code

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/util.js:57
            throw new Error('Current working directory is not a Cordova-based 
                  ^
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
    at Object.module.exports.cdProjectRoot (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/util.js:57:19)
    at CLI.plugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/plugin.js:28:36)
    at new CLI (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:109:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:41:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:native mohammadnurdin$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be in a project before you launch `cordova plugin search bar code`.

Comment: how to that? can u give me a scenario?

Answer (score 77):

If you are getting this error on ***Ionic2***
This issue generally occur when we just clone / download app and try to add platform to it.

its very easy to resolve, then here are the steps-

just create a "www" directory in application root.

```
"./www"
```

can also do by this command-

```
mkdir www
```

now we can easily run following command -

```
ionic platform add android
or
ionic platform add ios
```

Hope it will help!!!

Answer (score 58):

Solution is to make sure there's a www/ directory inside the root directory.

```
mkdir www
```

make sure your .gitignore file doesn't include `www/` directory on it.

Comment: Yes, someone put `www/` into gitignore and this fixed it.

Comment: A custom script that I use to deploy my app was accidentally moving the `www` directory out of the project root. This answer helped me notice the missing folder.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, as QuickFix said, you need to be in a Cordova project before being able to use most of cordova Commands. If you are curious about what defines a Cordova project, this is what I found:

- Has a .cordova directory, with a config.json inside.
- Has a www directory, with a config.xml inside.
- Has a platforms directory.

With that in place you can use Cordoba commands without problem. If you need examples of those config files just run `cordova create myapp`.

Answer (score 11):

Happened to me also, probably from npm/node updates.

Worked for me the following:

`npm install -g cordova`

`ionic cordova platform list`

Answer (score 1):

Create www folder on root directory. If still it's a issue check ionic info and try to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

1. run `ionic serve`
2. It will create www folder
3. Then run `cordova prepare`

Answer (score 1):

```
ionic integrations enable --add
```

then run the

```
ionic build
```

it will add all the necessary files

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. i had an angular project. then created a cordova app inside called mobile

```
cordova create mobile
```

Then i tried to run

```
cordova platform add android
```

Which gave me the same error 'Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project'.

Solution : i have to go to the mobile folder ( from the command prompt cd mobile ) then i had to run the command  there. Also there had to be a www folder in that mobile folder

Answer (score 0):

Did you come here because your Azure DevOps (fka VSO/VSTS) Cordova build pipe task failed with "Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project"?

Resolved by creating the required (and missing) folder 'www\', with a powershell having script:

`New-Item -ItemType directory -Path www\`

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a new project using the create command,you need to change the directory to the newly create project where you are going to build your app.

eg.
E:\Andriod\myapp>cordova create newapp
Creating a new cordova project.

E:\Andriod\myapp>cordova build
***Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.***

**E:\Andriod\myapp>cd newapp**

E:\Andriod\myapp\newapp>cordova build

it will be working at this point

Answer (score 0):

This may be silly but in my case it was the `config.xml` file.

I usually create it dynamically using a script, therefor it wasn't there after I cloned the repo. Ran the script to re-create it and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ionic cordova build [platform]
ex. ionic cordova build android
or for ios 
ionic cordova build ios
```

It will automatically create the www folder path.
see more commands here
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build

**[Note: Make sure you install ionic and cordova**

```
npm install -g ionic
npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score -1):

I cannot explain the source of the error, but in case you are looking for a solution, you might want to try [plugman](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html) instead.

Answer (score -1):

THis Solution helped me:
go to Root of your Project via cmd and run.

```
npm run build-cordova
```

after that just create new android platforms

`cordova platform rm android`
`cordova platform add android`

Answer (score -2):

you have to be in the current project in command prompt(example project name is myapp).

[image: example screen shot]