# Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project

Tags: cordova, android-studio

When i am running this code Error cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=ptw in cmd ,i am getting error "Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project."
Why this error is coming.I am unable to fix it.Here is the

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmb0W.png
Please suggest me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: please check the result of ls command

Comment: if you got the file like bower.json  gulpfile.js   plugins  www
config.xml  hooks  package.json scss

Comment: You have to be in a project before you launch

Comment: Not understood @Santosh Shinde

Comment: please let me know the result of ls or dir command

Comment: PS D:\> plugman config ls
; cli configs
cache = "C:\\Users\\Sradhanjali\\.plugman\\cache"
cache-min = 86400
registry = "http://localhost/PTWAPP/app/_rewrite"
user-agent = "npm/2.14.16 node/v4.2.4 win32 ia32"
userconfig = "C:\\Users\\Sradhanjali\\.plugman\\config"

; userconfig C:\Users\Sradhanjali\.plugman\config
registry = "http://localhost/PTWAPP/app/_rewrite"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = D:\
; HOME = C:\Users\Sradhanjali
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.

done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101757/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-srd).

Answer (score 4):

You have to be in a project before you launch

- Has a .cordova directory, with a config.json inside.
- Has a www directory, with a config.xml inside.
- Has a platforms directory.

If all is well then update your cordova

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Hopes this will help you !

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Ionic 2 (this also use cordova) then just follow this link-

[Cordova - Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276294/cordova-current-working-directory-is-not-a-cordova-based-project)

Hope it will work !!

Answer (score 0):

Working in my case
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/plugin-name