# Ionic macOS build issue wtih Azure DevOps

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-devops, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to build Ionic based framework (Cordova plugin included) for iOS using Azure DevOps - Hosted macOS agent. I have included xcode in the Demands section.

[image]

Added Cordova build task and set the platform value to 'ios'

[image]

But getting 'Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project' error. Am I missing anything?

```
2018-11-07T19:49:07.6357620Z Module cache at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules
2018-11-07T19:49:08.4403560Z cordova already installed.
2018-11-07T19:49:08.4959970Z Adding support plugin.
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2854590Z { CordovaError: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2855410Z     at Object.cdProjectRoot (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:170:15)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2856100Z     at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/plugin/index.js:36:40
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2856540Z     at _fulfilled (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2856690Z     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2856810Z     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2858330Z     at /Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:877:14
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2858660Z     at runSingle (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2858880Z     at flush (/Users/vsts/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/8.1.2/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2859360Z     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2859510Z     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2860600Z   name: 'CordovaError',
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2861150Z   message: 'Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.',
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2861220Z   code: 0,
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2861360Z   context: undefined }
2018-11-07T19:49:09.2972390Z ##[error]Task failed
```

Comment: Did you try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276294/cordova-current-working-directory-is-not-a-cordova-based-project) ?

Comment: @Jayendran none of the mentioned solution works for me. As I mentioned, this is running on Azure DevOps pipeline. So not sure how to use multiple commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following instead of cordova build

- npm install
- Ionic command (Command: ionic cordova build ios)
- Install an apple certificate
- Install an apple provisioning profile
- Xcode build
- Publish to the app store (install from marketplace)